# Read contract variable with only interface definition

Tags: smartcontracts

I'm playing ethernaut Level 3, the original contract is here: https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0x4dF32584890A0026e56f7535d0f2C6486753624f

When consecutiveWins is bigger or equal to 10, the player wins:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import '@openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol';

contract CoinFlip {

  using SafeMath for uint256;
  uint256 public consecutiveWins;

  ...
}
```

Now I want to read the `consecutiveWins` value in my contract, so I defined an interface:

```
interface CoinFlip {
   uint256 public consecutiveWins;
   function flip(bool _guess) external returns (bool);
}
```

But it is not allowed to have a variable in an interface, what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solidity compiler will automatically generate getter functions for public variables, so what you need is replacing `consecutiveWins` variable in your interface with a getter function like this:

```
function consecutiveWins() public view returns (uint256);
```

You can read more about it in Solidity docs [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters).